# Help me understand this solved problem.

Tags: calculus

> $$
> \lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{9/2}-a^{9/2}}{x^{1/2} - a^{1/2}} = \lim_{y \to b}\frac{y^9 - b^9}{y-b}\\
> = \lim_{y \to b}(y^8 + by^7 + b^2y^6 + b^3y^5 + b^4y^4 + b^5y^3 + b^6y^2 + b^7y + b^8)\\
> = 9b^8\\
> = 9(\sqrt a)^8\\
> = 9a^4
> $$

I copied this from my guide book while practicing, but I don't fully understand the steps done here. Can someone explain them individually?

Comment: here $y = \sqrt{x}$ and $b = \sqrt{a}$. This should have been mentioned in the solution. Moreover the following general formula is used here $$X^{n} - Y^{n} = (X - Y)(X^{n - 1} + X^{n - 2}Y + \cdots + XY^{n - 2} + Y^{n - 1})$$